# zipWith-ing List of Integers with List of Functions

Tags: haskell

How can I zip a `[Integer]` with a `[Integer -> Integer -> Integer]` to get `[Integer -> Integer]`?

Example:

I tried:

```
Prelude> zipWith [1,2,3] (replicate 3 (*))
```

with the desired result of:

`[(*1), (*2), (*3)]`

But I got an error:

```
<interactive>:25:9:
    Couldn't match expected type `(a0 -> a0 -> a0) -> b0 -> c0'
                with actual type `[t0]'
    In the first argument of `zipWith', namely `[1, 2, 3]'
    In the expression: zipWith [1, 2, 3] (replicate 3 (*))
    In an equation for `it': it = zipWith [1, 2, 3] (replicate 3 (*))
```

**EDIT**  [@artyom-kazak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615030/artyom-kazak) corrected me - thank you.

Looks like I can do it with Applicatives:

```
Prelude Control.Applicative> let f = [(*)] <*> [1,2,3]
Prelude Control.Applicative> :t f
f :: [Integer -> Integer]
```

But, can I do this with `zipWith` alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. There's an operator for application, `$`, which is useful in exactly such cases.

```
> :t zipWith ($) [(*),(*),(*)] [1..3]
zipWith ($) [(*),(*),(*)] [1..3] :: (Num b, Enum b) => [b -> b]
```

And if you want to have `[1..3]` first, it's `zipWith (flip ($))`.

---

Also, your Applicative variant is wrong, if only because of this:

```
> let f = [(*), (*), (*)] <*> [1,2,3]
> length f
9
```

Comment: thank you for this answer and correcting me on my bad applicative.